# Two tableviews in one view controller and height of tableviews should be equal to its content

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, xcode4

I am a new in-app ios development. I am trying to get a UI like this: -

[image]

Here two types of tables are attached with one table view. This design in andriod.

I tried in IOS and take one table view with custom header and in the header I set another table view. Like this:-

[image]

And set code like this : -

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    secondview?.frame.size = CGSize(width: tableViews.frame.width, height: secondtableViews.contentSize.height + 50 + tableViews.contentSize.height)
    secondview.layer.masksToBounds = true
}




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == tableViews {
        debugPrint(" first")
         return 50
    }else{
        debugPrint(" second")
        return 50
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == tableViews {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "skdjfhkjfhjkshfkhsdkfhjsd"
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "gcell")! as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "skdjfhkjfh    jkshfkhsdkfhjsd"
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

I change the height of main table view. It workes on some part height do not work according to the content of table view and the data of first table showing on second and second is showing on first. Can any one help me out from this design issue.

Comment: what your expected UI/UX? is top and bottom tableview have different scrolling behaviour?

Comment: No they should scroll like one table , its scrolling like one table, but the contant of first table moved to next and second content moved to first that is my main issue.

Comment: just use 1 tableview then, use different section and cell to make that UI

Comment: You can see in upper section the section height is given and in lower section height is not, and between them a title is also given

Comment: yes, you can use 1 tableview to do that UI, even in android its only need 1 recycleview

Comment: Can you plz give me any code or link, how to do that

Comment: you know you can have different kind of cell in 1 tableview right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218052/discussion-between-user3120670-and-aiwiguna).

Answer (score 0):

you should go with one tableview with TWO sections and TWO different type of cell...!